# insert a text outside the frame

Tags: plotting, frame

is it possible to insert a text outside the frame box?

I mean on the top left.

as shown in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, Epilog -> Text[StringForm["x ``", 10^"-3"], {0.05, 1.05}],
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, ImagePadding -> 20, PlotRangeClipping -> False]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon
Thanks, but it this solution is not general, and it should be altered depending on the type of the plot

Comment: For a more general solution used `Scaled` coordinates, e.g., `Text[StringForm["x ``", 10^"-3"], Scaled[{0.07, 1.05}]]` You should clarify what different types of plots to which you refer.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Thank you very much

Comment: You can also combine with graphics primitives using `Show[{` your plot `,Graphics[{`graphics primitives`}]}]`. For example `Show[{Plot[{Log[x], 2 Log[x]}, {x, .1, 1.5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}],Graphics[{White, Point[{-.2, 1.4}], Black, 
    Text[StringForm["x``", 10^"-3"], {-.1, 1.3}]}]}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @Nicholas G
thank you so much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ClearAll[addLabel]
addLabel = Show[#, 
    Epilog -> Text[#2, Scaled[{0, 1}], {-1, -1}], 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 30] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
plt1 = Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium];
plt2 = Plot[ 3 Sin @ x, {x, -3 Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium];
plt3 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium];
plt4 = Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200], 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium];
plt5 = RegionPlot[1/4 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> Medium];
plt6 = BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium];

plots = {plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4, plt5, plt6};

Multicolumn[addLabel[#, Style[Row[{"x", 10^"-3"}], 16]] & /@ plots, 3]
```

[image]

Use `Text[#2, Scaled[{1, 1}], {1, -1}]` to get:

[image]

Use `Text[#2, Scaled[{1, 1}], {1, 1.5}, {0, 1}]` to get:

[image]

Use `Text[#2, Scaled[{1, 0}], {-1, 1.5}, {0, 1}]` to get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but I find any time I'm forced to deal with `PlotRangeClipping` things start to get janky. My preferred way of doing this via the `Overlay[]` function.

It's lightweight, flexible, intuitive, and you can leave whatever plots you have as-is. If you need to add a little bit of `ImagePadding`, you can do so explicitly when you add the Overlay.

```
(*Plot Code*)
plt3 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, ImageSize -> Medium];

(*Overlay Code*)
Overlay[{
  Show[plt3, ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 15}}],
  Style[Row[{"x", 10^"-3"}], Black, FontSize -> 12]},
 Alignment -> {-0.91, 1}]
```

Which produces the following.

[image]

Alignment isn't explained super well in the Overlay documentation, so for those that need it:

`Alignment->{-1,-1}` is bottom left,

`Alignment->{1,1}` is top right,

`Alignment->{0,0}` is in the middle (not of the graph, but the entire graphic/plot).