# How to display label text outside plot range and enable PlotRangeClipping?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have been trying to modify a clipped graph by adding a text a label outside the frame, with no success so far.

Code for `contour` per request to get the rest of the code to run:

```
    ClearAll[Sbase, Vbase, Zbase, countour];
    Sbase = 50 10^3;
    Vbase = 240;
    Zbase = Vbase^2/Sbase;
    countour[M_, Zpu_, XR_] := 
        Circle[{M/Z Cos[\[Phi]], -M/Z Sin[\[Phi]]}, 1/Z] /. {Z -> Zpu Zbase, \[Phi] -> ArcTan[XR]}
```

This is my graph:

```
g1 = Graphics[
   Flatten[
    {Red,
     Table[countour[M, 0.02, 3], {M, 0.98, 1.02, 0.001}],
     Blue,
     Table[countour[M, 0.04, 1], {M, 0.98, 1.02, 0.001}]
     }
    ],
   Axes -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImagePadding -> {{All, 50}, {All, All}}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 0.3}, {-0.3, 0.3}}];
```

The `contour` function just produces circles with differing centers and radii. I am zooming in close to the origin and clipping everything else to get this:

[image: Frame with clipping]

All is fine up to now, but I also want to add text labels **outside** the clipped frame. My successful trials, along with what I see suggested online(including StackExchange), hinge on setting `PlotRangeClipping` to `False`, for example as suggested here: ["insert a text outside the frame"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233795/insert-a-text-outside-the-frame).

That does not work for me, because when I try it I get:

```
ClearAll[g1, addLabel];
addLabel = Show[#,
    Epilog -> Text[#2, Scaled[{1.02, 0.7}], {-1, -1}],
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    ImagePadding -> {{All, 50}, {All, All}}] &;
g1 = Graphics[
   Flatten[
    {Red,
     Table[countour[M, 0.02, 3], {M, 0.98, 1.02, 0.001}],
     Blue,
     Table[countour[M, 0.04, 1], {M, 0.98, 1.02, 0.001}]
     }
    ],
   Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 0.3}, {-0.3, 0.3}}];
addLabel[g1, Style["M\[Equal]1", 16, Red]]
```

[image]

Which is not what I want at all. If I try to keep `PlotRangeClipping` as 'True` I lose the text label.

Any recommended workarounds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a graphics object with your primitives, using the desired plot range, with clipping and no image padding:

```
g1 = Graphics[
    Flatten[{
        Red,
        Table[countour[M,0.02,3],{M,0.98,1.02,0.001}],
        Blue,
        Table[countour[M,0.04,1],{M,0.98,1.02,0.001}]
    }],
    PlotRangeClipping->True,
    ImagePadding->0,
    PlotRange->{{-0.3,0.3},{-0.3,0.3}}
];
```

Then, inset this graphics object into your graphic, along with the text labels and your overall axes/frame specifications:

```
Graphics[
    {
    Inset[g1, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {.6, .6}],
    Text[Style["M\[Equal]1",16,Red],Scaled[{1.02,0.7}],{-1,-1}]
    },
    PlotRange -> {{-.3, .3}, {-.3, .3}},
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 50}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
    Frame -> True,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesLabel -> {x,y},
    AxesStyle -> Thick
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Thank you ! This worked exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can also clip the graphics primitives:

```
ClearAll[clip]
clip[prange_] := RegionIntersection[Rectangle @@ Transpose[prange], #] /. _EmptyRegion -> {} &;
```

Wrap your `countour[...]`s with `clip[plotrange]`

```
plotrange = {{-0.3, 0.3}, {-0.3, 0.3}};

g2 = Graphics[Flatten[{Red, 
     Table[clip[plotrange] @ countour[M, 0.02, 3], {M, 0.98, 1.02, 0.001}], 
     Blue, Table[clip[plotrange] @ countour[M, 0.04, 1], {M, 0.98, 1.02, 0.001}]}], 
   Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> plotrange];

addLabel[g2, Style["M\[Equal]1", 16, Red]]
```

[image]

**Caveat:** This approach does not work with primitives like `FilledCurve`, `BezierCurve`, `BSPlineCurve`, and transformed primitives (e.g. primitives wrapped inside `GeometricTransformation`, `Translate`, `Rotate`, `Scale` etc.) which do not work with `RegionIntersection`.

Comment: This approach won't work for things like BSplineCurve, FilledCurve, etc. Not every graphics primitive is also a region primitive.

Comment: Thank you @Carl; great points.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but I find any time I'm forced to deal with `PlotRangeClipping` and `ImagePadding` things start to get janky. My preferred way of doing this via the `Overlay[]` function.

It's lightweight, fairly intuitive, and doesn't require moving all the labels out of your current plot.

```
(*Your Plot*)
ClearAll[Sbase, Vbase, Zbase, contour];

Sbase = 50 10^3;
Vbase = 240;
Zbase = Vbase^2/Sbase;
countour[M_, Zpu_, XR_] := 
 Circle[{M/Z Cos[\[Phi]], -M/Z Sin[\[Phi]]}, 
   1/Z] /. {Z -> Zpu Zbase, \[Phi] -> ArcTan[XR]}

g1 = Graphics[Flatten[{
     Red, Table[countour[M, 0.02, 3], {M, 0.98, 1.02, 0.001}],
     Blue, Table[countour[M, 0.04, 1], {M, 0.98, 1.02, 0.001}]
     }],
   Axes -> True,
   PlotRangeClipping -> True,
   AxesStyle -> Thick,
   AxesLabel -> {x, y},
   ImagePadding -> {{All, 50}, {All, All}},
   Frame -> True,
   PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 0.3}, {-0.3, 0.3}}];

(*My Overlay*)
Overlay[{
  g1,
  Style["M=1", Red, FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Times"]},
 Alignment -> {0.95, 0.4}]
```

Which produces the following.

[image]

Alignment isn't explained super well in the Overlay documentation, so for those that need it:

`Alignment->{-1,-1}` is bottom left,

`Alignment->{1,1}` is top right,

`Alignment->{0,0}` is in the middle (not of the graph, but the entire graphic/plot).